# Filecontents is not recognized

Tags: beamer, apacite, filecontents

I don't know how, but it seems that this file does not want to be compiled. Why? This is my mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{\Sherbrooke.bib}
@misc{Anzieu1994,
  author = {Anzieu, D.},
  year = {1994},
  title = {Le penser},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\section
\begin{frame}
\cite{Anzieu1994}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Références}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\Sherbrooke}
\renewcommand{\bibliographytypesize}{\small}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Filename with backslash?

Comment: apart from the backslash: the filecontents package is obsolete in a current latex.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ulrike Fischer points out in a comment, the `filecontents` package is obsolete; the `filecontents` environment is part of the LaTeX kernel these days.

Furthermore, as @campa observes, you have a backslash in your filename, and on top of that the `\section` without an argument also won't work. And of course, changing the definition of `\bibliographytypesize` after `\bibliography` is unlikely to do anything.

I'm not familiar with `apacite`, but I understand that it is also dated, and that using `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` (i.e. `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`) is preferred these days, so that's what I did here:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Sherbrooke.bib}
@misc{Anzieu1994,
  author = {Anzieu, D.},
  year = {1994},
  title = {Le penser},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Sherbrooke}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{Anzieu1994}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Références}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I hope that this can serve as a start!